# Eslint not working on emacs, complaining of "Checker definition probably flawed"

Tags: emacs, eslint

I am trying to set up eslint on emacs by writing this in .emacs:

```
(setq flycheck-disabled-checkers '(javascript-jshint))
(setq flycheck-checkers '(javascript-eslint))
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (flycheck-mode t)
            (tern-mode t)
            ))
```

What I am getting when trying to open js files then is this error message:

[image]

Just updated eslint to the latest version (1.3.1) and emacs to the latest version (24.5). Hoped that would help.

It didn't.

(I do have lots of old packages in `~/.emacs.d/elpa` directory that are left from the time I installed them on the previous emacs version (24.3). But I don't think that's causing any issues).

Could you please suggest how to solve this problem with eslint?